# Host Blazor Server on sub path

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I want to host my Blazor Server app under `http://myraspberry/sample`. That's why I've set the path base by calling `app.UsePathBase("/sample")`. Since everything is working fine on my Dev machine, I ship the app as a single executable to my Raspberry via `dotnet publish -r linux-arm -c Release /p:PublishSingleFile=true`. I can successfully start the app after configuring NGINX as reverse proxy and the logic is working, but it looks horrible. All the static assets (images, CSS, etc.) are not loaded - `HTTP 404`.

I've already tried `app.UseStaticFiles("/wwwroot")` and setting the base within `_Host.cshtml` to `<base href="~/sample" />` instead of `UsePathBase("/sample")` - both without success. But the necessary files are there - I can see them using `dir` on the Raspberry.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be a trivial problem: I just SSHed into my Raspberry and this set the `Content root path` of the app to `/home/myuser` instead of the deployment directory. After `cd /deploymentDirectory`, everything is working.